# Calculate if the change is greater than .25

Tags: r, data.table

Consider this data.table

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(id = c("01","01","01","01","01", "02","02","02",",02","02"),
                 change_total = c(.00,.90,-.10,.8,.3,.00,.90,-.10,.8,.3))
```

How can I calculate the if the change between rows per id is greater than 25 percent (`change_greater_than_25_percent`) from `change_total` and then if those "yes" are greater than 25 percent by row per id.
Which would look like this

```
dt2 <- data.table(id = c("01","01","01","01", "01","02","02","02","02","02"),
                 change_total = c(.00,.90,-.10,.8,.3,.00,.90,-.10,.8,.3),
                 change_greater_than_25_percent = c("no","yes","no","no","no","no","yes","no","no","no"),
                 change_greater_than_25_percent_greaterthan_25_percent_ofthe_time_by_id = c("no","yes","yes","yes","no","no","yes","yes","yes","no"))
```

Comment: Are those expected output correct?  I tried for the 'change_greater_than_25_percent' and is giving different output though based on your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the expected result for column `change_greater_than_25_percent`:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr) # piping used to improve readability
dt1[, change_greater_than_25_percent := 
      (change_total / shift(change_total, fill = Inf) - 1. > 0.25) %>%  
      fifelse("yes", "no"), by = id][]
```

> ```
>     id change_total change_greater_than_25_percent
>  1: 01          0.0                             no
>  2: 01          0.9                            yes
>  3: 01         -0.1                             no
>  4: 01          0.8                             no
>  5: 01          0.3                             no
>  6: 02          0.0                             no
>  7: 02          0.9                            yes
>  8: 02         -0.1                             no
>  9: 02          0.8                             no
> 10: 02          0.3                             no
> ```

Unfortunately, I do not  understand the exact definition of column `change_greater_than_25_percent_greaterthan_25_percent_ofthe_time_by_id`

> and then if those "yes" are greater than 25 percent by row per id

### Edit 1

If I understand correctly [Pan Dora's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68928973/calculate-if-the-change-is-greater-than-25/68930116?noredirect=1#comment121821873_68930116), the second column indicates where the *cumulative mean* of `change_greater_than_25_percent` (taken as 0, 1 values for `"no"`, `"yes"`) is greater than 0.25.

This is easier to compute if `"no"`and `"yes"` are replaced by the logical values `FALSE` and `TRUE`, resp., because according to `help("TRUE")`

> Logical vectors are coerced to integer vectors in contexts where a numerical value is required, with `TRUE` being mapped to `1L`, `FALSE` to `0L` and `NA` to `NA_integer_`.

```
library(data.table)
dt1[, change_greater_than_25_percent := 
      change_total / shift(change_total, fill = Inf) - 1. > 0.25, by = id][
        , change_greater_than_25_percent_greaterthan_25_percent_ofthe_time_by_id := 
          cumsum(change_greater_than_25_percent) / (1:.N) >= 0.25, by = id][]
```

> ```
>     id change_total change_greater_than_25_percent change_greater_than_25_percent_greaterthan_25_percent_ofthe_time_by_id
>  1: 01          0.0                          FALSE                                                                  FALSE
>  2: 01          0.9                           TRUE                                                                   TRUE
>  3: 01         -0.1                          FALSE                                                                   TRUE
>  4: 01          0.8                          FALSE                                                                   TRUE
>  5: 01          0.3                          FALSE                                                                  FALSE
>  6: 02          0.0                          FALSE                                                                  FALSE
>  7: 02          0.9                           TRUE                                                                   TRUE
>  8: 02         -0.1                          FALSE                                                                   TRUE
>  9: 02          0.8                          FALSE                                                                   TRUE
> 10: 02          0.3                          FALSE                                                                  FALSE
> ```

### Notes

1. In order to reproduce the expected result *greater than or equal to 25 percent* (`>= 0.25`) had be to used instead of  *greater than 25 percent* (`> 0.25`). I refrained from amending the already long column name.
2. The use of logical values instead of character simplifies calculation so that we do not need *`magrittr` piping*.
3. *`data.table` chaining* is used.
4. For computing the *cumulative mean*, `dplyr::cummean()` or *adaptive* `frollmean()` can be used alternatively.

### Edit 2

Above code requires `dt1` to be of class `data.table`. To make sure, please call

```
setDT(dt1)
```

beforehand.

Comment: that column change_greater_than_25_percent_greaterthan_25_percent_ofthe_time_by_id means, line 1 change_greater_than_25_percent is no then add it to line two change_greater_than_25_percent if that is greater than 25 percent "yes" or it is lower then"no" Example in this case line1 is no line two is yes so there avg is 50% which causes a yes for the column change_greater_than_25_percent_greaterthan_25_percent_ofthe_time_by_id. then add line 3 which is a "no" the average is now 33% of yes so that would be a "yes" so forth

Comment: the column "change_greater_than_25_percent_greaterthan_25_percent_ofthe_time_by_id" means, line 1 change_greater_than_25_percent is a  "no" then add it to line two change_greater_than_25_percent if that is greater than 25 percent "yes" or it is lower then "no" Example in this case line1 is "no" line two is "yes" so there avg is 50% which causes a yes for the column "change_greater_than_25_percent_greaterthan_25_percent_ofthe_time_by_id". then add line 3 which is a "no" the average is now 33% of "yes" so that would be a "yes" so forth

Comment: This is the error code when I run your code Error in as.vector(x,list): cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'list'

Comment: @PanDora Thank you for the additional explanation! Concerning the error, please, see my 2nd edit. If the error persists, we might have to further inspect the input data.